# CSS - Ao clicar em um checkbox... pintar uma TD

Tags: css, html5

Estou tentando fazer o seguinte: 
Ao clicar em uma check box, ela pinta o fundo de laranja... 
Precisava que pintasse também o background da TD, pois atualmente só está pintando o fundo da label... 
Como posso pintar juntamente o fundo da td?

```css
input.check-genero:hover + label,
input.check-genero:checked + label{
-webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
-ms-transform: scale(1.2);
transform: scale(1.2);
}

/* Tabela conteúdo */
table.tabela-categoria{
border: solid 15px #fff;
}

.tabela-categoria td{
border: solid 2px #d3d1d1;
text-align: center;
padding: 5px;
width: 140px;
}

.categoria + label{
font-family: verdana;
font-size: 1.2em;
color: #727176;
cursor: pointer;
}

.categoria:hover + label,
.categoria:checked + label{
color: #ffffff;
background-color:#FF6600;
}
```

```html
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cont10" id="estilo" class="categoria">
        <label for="estilo">ESTILO</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cont11" id="entretenimento" class="categoria">
        <label for="entretenimento">ENTRETENIMENTO</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cont12" id="familia" class="categoria">
        <label for="familia">TESTE</label>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: possuí conhecimento em javascript?, muito provavelmente a resposta a seguir será utilizando ele.

Comment: Estou estudando JavaScript também, porém se tivesse um meio via CSS seria perfeito, mas se neste caso será somente por javaScript, eu entendo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara, vc não vai conseguir colorir o fundo da TD assim. Vc não consegue pegar o elemento **parent** num seletor css.

O que vc pode fazer é, ao clicar, adicionar na td (parent) uma classe 'selected' ou de nome que desejar. Então você estiliza tudo baseado nessa classe.

Para adicionar a classe no click, você deve usar jquery ou vanilla js (que é o Js puro).

Abaixo tem um exemplo para você:

```js
var $table = document.querySelector('.minha-table');

$table.addEventListener("click", function(ev){  
  if (ev.target.tagName == "INPUT") {
    if (ev.target.checked) {
      ev.target.parentNode.parentNode.classList.add("selected");
    }else {
      ev.target.parentNode.parentNode.classList.remove("selected");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
table td {
  padding: 5px;
  background: #ccc;
}

td.selected {
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<table class="minha-table">
  <tr>
    <td><label><input type="checkbox"> teste </label></td>
    <td><label><input type="checkbox"> teste </label></td>
    <td><label><input type="checkbox"> teste </label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Criei um [texto no blog](http://www.josejunior.com.br/2018/02/16/como-colorir-td-com-checkbox-checked/) explicando detalhadamente como cheguei na solução abaixo.

Comment: Entendi !! Muito obrigado @José

Comment: José, uma resposta adequada, tem exemplos de como a coisa funciona. Lembrando que o problema não é resolvido apenas com framworks, o javascript puro também resolve o problema, apesar do Jquery ser uma mão nada roda :)

Comment: Vale lembrar que logo logo teremos como referenciar o elemento pai com css, especificação https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

Comment: Aí facilitará muito !!

Comment: @Bsalvo 'vanilla js' citado na resposta é o js puro ;) rsrs.

Verdade, vou colocar um exemplo de como ficaria com js puro e jquery. Valew pela dica.

Answer (score 0):

Como vc falou nos comentários que gostaria de uma versão apenas com CSS fiz esse modelo que pode te atender.

Não mexi no seu HTML apenas algumas linhas do CSS

```css
input.check-genero:hover + label,
input.check-genero:checked + label{
-webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
-ms-transform: scale(1.2);
transform: scale(1.2);
}

/* Tabela conteúdo */
table.tabela-categoria{
border: solid 15px #fff;
}

.tabela-categoria td{
border: solid 2px #d3d1d1;
text-align: center;
padding: 5px;
width: 140px;
}

.categoria + label{
font-family: verdana;
font-size: 1.2em;
color: #727176;
cursor: pointer;
}

.categoria:checked + label{
color: #ffffff;
background-color:#FF6600;
}
.categoria:checked + label::after{
content: "";
background-color:#FF6600;
background-size: 100%;
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
}
td {
position: relative;
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <input type="checkbox" name="cont10" id="estilo" class="categoria">
   <label for="estilo">ESTILO</label>
  </td>
  <td>
   <input type="checkbox" name="cont11" id="entretenimento" class="categoria">
   <label for="entretenimento">ENTRETENIMENTO</label>
  </td>
  <td>
   <input type="checkbox" name="cont12" id="familia" class="categoria">
   <label for="familia">TESTE</label>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```